# Some preliminary concepts for Rota-Baxter algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, semidirect-product, free-product

I am studying Rota-Baxter Lie algebras. I do not know whether there exists the notion of free product, semi-direct product and derivation map for these types of algebras. May you introduce some papers or give me some explanation regarding this concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a starter, [this article](http://www.ams.org/notices/200911/rtx091101436p.pdf) is quite nice; it has a reference to the authors resources (in particular to his book on Rota-Baxter (Lie) algebras). We have an article on [Rota-Baxter operators and Lie algebras](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_59_rota.pdf), which might be helpful, including the references.
Rota-Baxter Lie algebras are closely related to pre-Lie algebras and post-Lie algebras.